# Migrating SP2010 List Items to Office 365 creates empty items in O365 [CSOM]

Tags: 2010, list, office-365, migration, client-object-model

I am trying to migrate SharePoint 2010 list items to an O365 list. **But when the code is executed, it creates empty list items in O365 list** even though "newItem" has the correct key value pair. Here "**liCol**" is the collection of list items in the SP2010 list.

```
                foreach (ListItem li in liCol)
                    {
                        ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                        ListItem newItem = list.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);

                        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> liField in li.FieldValues)
                        {

                            bool isFieldReadOnly = false;
                            string itemFieldName = liField.Key;

                            Field field = list.Fields.GetByTitle(itemFieldName);
                            c.Load(field);
                            c.ExecuteQuery();
                            isFieldReadOnly = field.ReadOnlyField;

                            if (!isFieldReadOnly)
                            {
                                newItem[itemFieldName] = li[itemFieldName];
                            }

                        }

                        newItem.Update();                     

                    }
                  list.Update();
                  c.ExecuteQuery();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you to look into the Migration API for that kind of use case. There are Powershell commands that can do it for you or 3rd party tools doing that kind of work. To get an idea of what the format of the content needs to be I would recommend running an SPweb-Export of the list with the uncompressed parameter for you to see how it would look like.

[Video explaining the summary of how it works.](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK3153)

[API doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.site.createmigrationjob.aspx)

[PowerShell Commands in preview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt203955.aspx)